# Как повесить обработчик на функцию использующую .each

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть вот такая функция (скрывает элемент, если он превышает высоту 60px), как повесить на нее обработчик, чтобы она срабатывала на вновь созданные элементы. Т.е. проверяла высоту в динамически созданных элементах. Не могу понять как связать .on и .each

```js
  $(".review_card_text__p").each(function readmore() {
        if ( $(this).height() < 60) {
            $(this).closest(".review_card").find(".review_card_text-up").toggleClass( "review_card_text-up__none");
            $(this).closest(".review_card").find(".review_card_text").toggleClass("review_card_text_opacity");
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если воспользоваться [ответом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268661/jquery-on-create-event-for-dynamically-created-elements)

и немного поменять то можно прикинуть такое

```js
(function($) {
      // назначение обработчика domNodeInserted на изменение в документе
      
      $(document).on("domNodeInserted", "select", function() {
        $(".review_card_text__p").each(function readmore() {
        if ( $(this).height() < 60) {
            $(this).closest(".review_card").find(".review_card_text-up").toggleClass( "review_card_text-up__none");
            $(this).closest(".review_card").find(".review_card_text").toggleClass("review_card_text_opacity");
        }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
//создание event

  (function($) {

    var observers = [];

    $.event.special.domNodeInserted = {

      setup: function setup(data, namespaces) {
        var observer = new MutationObserver(checkObservers);

        observers.push([this, observer, []]);
      },

      teardown: function teardown(namespaces) {
        var obs = getObserverData(this);

        obs[1].disconnect();

        observers = $.grep(observers, function(item) {
          return item !== obs;
        });
      },

      remove: function remove(handleObj) {
        var obs = getObserverData(this);

        obs[2] = obs[2].filter(function(event) {
          return event[0] !== handleObj.selector && event[1] !== handleObj.handler;
        });
      },

      add: function add(handleObj) {
        var obs = getObserverData(this);

        var opts = $.extend({}, {
          childList: true,
          subtree: true
        }, handleObj.data);

        obs[1].observe(this, opts);

        obs[2].push([handleObj.selector, handleObj.handler]);
      }
    };

    function getObserverData(element) {
      var $el = $(element);

      return $.grep(observers, function(item) {
        return $el.is(item[0]);
      })[0];
    }

    function checkObservers(records, observer) {
      var obs = $.grep(observers, function(item) {
        return item[1] === observer;
      })[0];

      var triggers = obs[2];

      var changes = [];

      records.forEach(function(record) {
        if (record.type === 'attributes') {
          if (changes.indexOf(record.target) === -1) {
            changes.push(record.target);
          }

          return;
        }

        $(record.addedNodes).toArray().forEach(function(el) {
          if (changes.indexOf(el) === -1) {
            changes.push(el);
          }
        })
      });

      triggers.forEach(function checkTrigger(item) {
        changes.forEach(function(el) {
          var $el = $(el);

          if ($el.is(item[0])) {
            $el.trigger('domNodeInserted');
          }
        });
      });
    }

  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение проблемы.

```js
var ReviewCards = {
    init: function() {
       this.checkTextHeight();
    },
    
   checkTextHeight: function(){
        $(".review_card_text__p").each(function readmore() {
            if ( $(this).height() < 61) {
                $(this).closest(".review_card").find(".review_card_text-up").addClass( "review_card_text-up__none");
                $(this).closest(".review_card").find(".review_card_text").addClass("review_card_text_opacity");
            }
        });
    },
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    ReviewCards.init();
});
```